# Why won't this if statement work? New to python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figure out for the life of me why this if statement isn't working in Python 3. I have always worked with python 2.7 but I need to get familiar with 3. Here is my code

```
print("Answer the question! [(Y)es or (N)o]: ")
answer = input()
print(answer)

if answer == "y":
    print("OK")

print("done")
```

I start this code, get presented with the question, ok, that's normal. For input I give it a single lowercase y. I see that 'y' printed back to me, but then the program bypasses the if statement and goes straight to done. What simple thing am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does it print if you `print(repr(answer))`?  What about `print(repr("y"))`?

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me with Python 3.3. Assuming it is as the others say below (and above) - there must be something with the input.

Comment: Is this an *exact copy* of the code you are running?

Comment: Try `if answer.strip() == "y":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for starters, your code works! I've tested it online and it works. Probably something with your IDE or with whatever Python you are using. I've had errors like this when using Jython.

[image: But it works here!]

Comment: Hmm, must be something to do with aptana. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any problem http://ideone.com/Vk9Hdo,
Try this:

```
print("Answer the question! [(Y)es or (N)o]: ")
answer = input()
print(answer)

if answer == "y":
    print("OK")

print("done")
```

Output

```
Answer the question! [(Y)es or (N)o]: 
y
OK
done
```

Comment: `raw_input` does not exist in Python 3.  It was renamed to `input`.

Comment: What makes you think changing `"y"` to `'y'` is going to make any difference?

Comment: You may be running into the same issue that a few of us have alluded to - the code as posted seems to work fine :).

Comment: Save one line of code:
`answer = input("Answer the question! [(Y)es or (N)o]: ")
    print(answer)

    if answer == "y":
       print("OK")`

    print("done")